# Can not open Mail app since I updated the last version of Mountain Lion (10.8.2)

Tags: macos, mail.app, error, versions

I just updated my version of Mountain Lion and then when I try to open my Mail app I receive this message :

[image: error screen shot]

I tried to reinstall Mail but I don't know how to do it.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Are you opening the correct Mail.app? Sounds silly but perhaps the shortcut in your dock is not pointing at the latest version. Does the same message appear when opening Mail from your Applications directory?

Comment: Yes, it's the same message from anywhere I open the app. I already verified if I haven't several Mail app installed on my computer. But I just have only one...

Comment: This seems really weird. I'm still on Version 6.0 (1486) of Mail but, granted, I've been due a system update for a while. I'll do one tonight and see where it takes me.

Comment: actually in the help they say that maybe the Mail app was not correctly updated and I need to reinstall it... How can I do this?

Comment: If you happen to live in the vicinity of an Apple Store, I suggest you take it there and save yourself some trouble. Here is something I found online that you can give a try:1. Download Pacifist.(http://www.charlessoft.com/) 

2. Re-download the Mountain Lion installer (if it was deleted). 

3 . Use Pacifist to re-install Mail.app (EssentialSystemSoftware > EssentialSystemSoftwareGroup > Essentials.pkg > Applications > Mail.app).  Credit: http://www.modelmayhem.com/po.php?thread_id=853200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version of Mail.app for OS X 10.8.2 (in my case build 12C60) would be 6.2, so your version is too old. Try software update, if that doesn't show anything reinstall the [OS X 10.8.2 Combo Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1581) manually. Run software update again after (re)installing this.